# Converting a *.c/*.h project (compiled as C++) to *.cpp/*.hpp

Tags: c++, batch-file, include, rename

Question: what is the best way to convert a *.c/*.h based project (which is forcefully compiled as C++ via the makefiles) to a *.cpp/*.hpp based project?

Obviously, this is a triple-step process. The first would be to rename everything with *.c at the end to *.cpp; the second would be to rename everything with *.h at the end to *.hpp. What I'm getting caught up on is the third step- somehow building a list of what the files /were/ named (ie, myfile.c), then iterating through every single affected file and replacing every instance of the old filename with the new (myfile.c -> myfile.cpp). Obviously this would have to be done so the source files can still find everything that they need.

The source code in question consists of around 2700 individual source files.

The reason why I'm doing this is mostly because I'm porting said software package to Mac OS X, and that involves Xcode. Things are getting bloody messy trying to keep track of precisely what is C, C++, and the associated headers for either (then overriding the compiler for C++ compilation). It would be much simpler if everything C++ was *.cpp (with the associated headers being *.hpp), since then I can just leave Xcode at the default compiler setting as per the file extension and everything should work without any fancy intervention on my end.

I should probably also note that I know precisely what files need to be converted, because they already compile properly and in a sane fashion if I'm overriding Xcode to compile as C++. That's not a problem- my issue is trying to figure out how to batch rename everything then run through all the files and update the #includes.

Thank you in advance!
-Keven Tipping

Comment: Why are you compiling .c files as C++?

Comment: @Adam: because they contain C++ code?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to mess with the headers.  filename.h is a perfectly good name for a C++ header.

If you're not using the old makefile, but creating a new XCode project, then you have only one step:

- Rename *.c to *.cpp

If the makefile was written right (using rule patterns and not specific per-file rules), there shouldn't be any changes needed there either.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to rename those C language header and source files to C++ and there are many reasons not to. Just three of the many:

Reason #1: C and C++ are diverging, different languages. Force-compiling a C file as if it were C++ risks introducing a bug.

Reason #2: Xcode can handle C, C++, and C and C++ mixed together.

Reason #3: C++ can easily call C routines. All you need to do is wrap the declarations of those C functions inside an `extern "C" { /* C declarations here */ }` construct.

Comment: It sounds as if the .c files really contain C++ source.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the OP. I think he's saying his project is *already* building .c files as C++ (which is bizarro anyways), and he wants to normalize the filenames.

Comment: Quixoto is correct. The project already builds as a set of *.c files- only because the makefiles are setup to force the compilation of /all/ C files as C++. If you do not force the compilation of the source as C++, then it fails miserably- as the *.c files are more C++ then they are plain old C. Hence my original question- I'm looking for a way to batch-rename all *.c source files and all *.h source files to their *.cpp and *.hpp equivalents, then iterate over each file and make sure that the #includes are all pointing at the updated names.

Comment: If that is all you are trying to do, Ben's answer is the right one: Just rename your xxx.c files so they have a valid C++ suffix, one .cc, .cp, .cxx, .cpp, .c++, .CPP, or .C (although I would recommend against the latter two on a Mac, where file names by default are case insensitive). There is no reason to rename your header files.